# Ubuntu Server 21.10 on Raspberry Pi 4 - text displays off to the left on

Tags: server, display, raspberrypi, 21.10, overscan

I just installed Ubuntu Server 21.10 on my Raspberry Pi 4. Problem is I can't read everything that's displayed because the first 6 or 7 characters are off to the left off the screen (not viewable).

How do I adjust or resize my view? I'm pretty new to Linux and I'm trying but not seeing everything makes this waaay harder. And I've plugged the Raspberry Pi into 2 different tv's. Both 50" via hdmi. So I know it's not the specific tv's.

Comment: This is usually the result of "overscan" on the TV. If you can disable the setting (on the TV), then you should see the full width of the console 

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried adjusting the overscan as you suggested. Option were only On/Off. It was on so I switched it off. The display view didn't change. I also powered off the tv, then back on again. Checked to make sure Overscan was still off and rebooted the pi. So unfortunately nope to that idea. Is there a linux command where I can adjust the output screen size?

Comment: Usually, the overscan is adjustable. Can you use a different display? Or, because you are using Ubuntu server, can you just use SSH?

Answer (score 0):

To change the display resolution on Ubuntu Server, you will need to modify your Grub boot loader settings. Fortunately, it's not too difficult.

Here's how you do it:

0. Connect to the server (either via SSH or on the device itself)
1. Edit the Grub file with `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/default/grub
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice.</sup>
2. Add a `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX` parameter to the bottom of the file with the resolution that you would like:

   ```
   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768
   ```
3. Save the file.
4. Update Grub:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Reboot.

Depending on the native resolution of your TVs, you may need to adjust the resolution to match the display ratio. Ubuntu Server works with 4:3 resolutions by default while your 50" displays are likely 16:9 or 16:10. This sort of thing can create some issues depending on the type of TV you're connecting to.

Comment: Thanks very much for the direction..before I can try Step 0, I'm working my way through installing the correct files to connect the ubuntu server to my wifi..to be able to SSH into my raspberry so i can move on to Step 1. Connecting to the device leads me right back to the original problem of not seeing part of my input and part of the output.  Side note everything looks fine when i plug into an old CRT monitor...so for sure the issue is related to my 2 tv's I tried connecting. Anyway I just wanted to acknowledge your help, and say thanks in advance - fingers crossed.

Comment: Oh while I'm at this, I'm a linux/ubuntu noob. So I don't have an "editor of choice". Can you recommend one?  Thanks again.